# Add post order to function (php)

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add post order to this function? I would like to display most recent post from newest to oldest:

```
<?php
//Establish first post check variable
$first_post = true;

query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=3');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
            <p class="news_title"><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo wp_trim_words( $title , '4', $more = null ); ?></p></a>
            <?php if($first_post) { ?>
                <div class="post_skrot"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $num_words = 8, $more = '... <a class="button_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">show more >> </a>' ); ?></div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="post_skrot"><a class="button_more" href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">show more>> </a></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </li>

        <?php
        //Change value of $first_post
        $first_post = false;
    endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I try add

```
&orderby=date&order=ASC
```

but it doesn't work.

Whole code:

```
 <div id="sliders-2-3">
            <div class="elementy-oferty">

                <div class="slider-4">
                    <div class="border-video">
                        <div class="content-slider-4">
                            <div class="blog_top_title"><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></div>
                        <ul>
                            <?php
//Establish first post check variable
$first_post = true;

$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'cat' => 317,
        'orderby' => 'DESC'

        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


        <div class="blog_post_sekcja">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
            <p class="news_title"><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo wp_trim_words( $title , '4', $more = null ); ?></p></a>
            <?php if($first_post) { ?>
                <div class="post_skrot"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $num_words = 30, $more = '... <a class="button_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">pokaż więcej » </a>' ); ?></div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="post_skrot"><a class="button_more" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">pokaż więcej » </a></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        //Change value of $first_post
        $first_post = false;
    endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="blog_more">
                        <a href="/blog.html" title="Blog" class="button_more">Więcej wpisów</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I've got: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file...on line 145. 145 is my last line in code and on this line I have only `<?php get_footer(); ?>`

I think it must be something with `endwhile;` or another syntax.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does it return anything when you don't include `&orderby=date&order=ASC`?

Comment: @MattBuresh yes, the same. I have post form dates 9.05, 8.05, 7.05, 6.05. Function displays it in order 7.05, 6.05, 9.05

Comment: Not sure about this, but I know `showposts` is deprecated, and might cause issues with the query. Does changing it to `posts_per_page` change anything?

Comment: @MattBuresh unfortunately no, the same.

Comment: Official ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $args array is off a little bit. Should be:

```
<div id="sliders-2-3">
<div class="elementy-oferty">

   <div class="slider-4">
       <div class="border-video">
           <div class="content-slider-4">
               <div class="blog_top_title"><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></div>
               <ul>
               <?php
                //Establish first post check variable
                $first_post = true;

                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'cat' => 317,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC' // or 'ASC like in your original code.'
                );

                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="blog_post_sekcja">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
                            <p class="news_title"><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo wp_trim_words( $title , '4', $more = null ); ?></p></a>
                            <?php if ( $first_post ) : ?>
                                <div class="post_skrot"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $num_words = 30, $more = '... <a class="button_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">pokaż więcej » </a>' ); ?></div>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <div class="post_skrot"><a class="button_more" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">pokaż więcej » </a></div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        $first_post = false;
                    }  
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
               </ul>
               <div class="blog_more">
               <a href="/blog.html" title="Blog" class="button_more">Więcej wpisów</a></div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: When I paste that code I have -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in  ... This is before `// You post content goes here.` then starts my content with <div... Could you fit the code to my whole code I paste above?

Comment: You are master @MattBuresh! It works - thank you very much :)